# ssd and cpu upgrade windows not installing

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, ssd

A recently purchased ssd drive is reluctant to boot with a new windows installation.  Windows simply wont load after its first reboot in the midst of install and previously displayed a bootmbr post error before i prioritized my dvd drive.  Help is sincerely appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I suggest to make a Hirens boot CD (or sth like that), boot form it and first check if ssd has (or has not) any errors.

Comment: What is the error you are currently getting and exactly when in the process do you get it?

Comment: Im not getting any particular error at present but the start screen hangs and doesn't seem to move on to the next stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.  The problem wasn't the SSD and was something to do with my SATA configuration with several large capacity SATA-2 drives.  It works find with them disconnected, and it might need a RAID configuration enabled in the BIOS but would thus require a new Windows install.